# Trouble mounting/formating 16g SanDisk USB

Tags: 13.04, usb, mount, usb-drive, format

I'm having trouble mounting or formating my 16gig SanDisk USB. When I run

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

I get this return

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 16.0 GB, 16008609792 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 15267 cylinders, total 31266816 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00041d5f
```

and when I use the Disks Utility to try and format the device I get this error

[image: Screenshot from User (originally placed on Google, uploaded to imgur by Thomas W.)]
[(image source)](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/106691702488567678641/albums/5918687437548562465/5918687439953964338?authkey=CKSo7cHnyffZhAE)

What would be the best way to mount this device, or format it so it can be readily available every time I plug it in? Is there something else hindering this device from mounting that I am not aware of?

```
*I Have a Acer Aspire M5-581t 6807 
-Intel® Core™ i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4 
-Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
-6gigs of ram 
-20gb ssd 
-500gb hdd
-lintel 4000 graphics
*I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i've not seen such error before, but you may try this: it may work

- Format it:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc
```

For mounting it:

```
mkdir /media/mountPoint
```

```
 mount /dev/sdc /media/mountPoint
```

p.s: Check if device is **/dev/sdc** or **/dev/sdb**

Second way to do it (**UI**):

```
                 Use **Gparted**
```

Install it by

```
 sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Run it:

```
 sudo gparted
```

Go to top right corner and select the disk and do whatever operation it required ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Install Gparted.  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Once done, insert the USB key. Now launch GParted. To do that go to dash and search for GParted.  Once open just follow the steps shown in the images below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Once done, remove the USB, and re-insert, and it should mount.

Comment: What if the flash drive isn't recognized by Gparted or anything else for that matter except windows and `lsusb`?

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem but, in Gparted, I unmounted the device then I could work with it, deleted the partition and created a new identical one. Now it is OK.